# Specifying emmeans for negative binomial model

Tags: glm, emmeans, posthoc

I've been trying out different models for my count data that is zero inflated and it looks like after looking at the Akaike information criterion (AIC) and the rootgram of different models, the generalized linear model negative binomial is the best fit. I'd like to do a post-hoc on my data but I keep running into some errors and I'm not sure the best way to frame the code in order to get what I'm looking for.

I used the following code for the model, where "flwrs" is my response variable (the count data), "tre" is a treatment group (which there are four of - F400, F800, GE400, GE800, and "wa" is for my weeks after transplant (ranging from 1-26).

```
negbin <- glm.nb(flwrs ~ tre*wa + (1 | replic), data = test)
summary(negbin)
Anova(negbin)
```

With the anova I see p < 2.2e-16 for tre, wa, and tre:wa. I'd like to explore more the significance between the tre and wa in particular.

```
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)

Response: flwrs
           LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
tre           263.6  3  < 2.2e-16 ***
wa           4423.8 25  < 2.2e-16 ***
1 | replic           0               
tre:wa        531.1 72  < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

When I try to do a post-hoc with emmeans though I keep running into errors that I can't seem to work through.

This is what I tried based on what I read about emmeans in the help tab of R

```
emm <- emmeans(negbin, ~ tre | wa)
pairs(emm, adjust = "tukey")
```

The reponse is this :

```
> emm <- emmeans(negbin, ~ tre | wa)
Error in `[.data.frame`(tbl, , vars, drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected
Error in (function (object, at, cov.reduce = mean, cov.keep = get_emm_option("cov.keep"),  : 
  Perhaps a 'data' or 'params' argument is needed

> pairs(emm, adjust = "tukey")
Error in if (nc < 2L) stop("only one column in the argument to 'pairs'") : 
  argument is of length zero
```

So I'm not very sure how to specify parameters or define the columns. Mainly I'm hoping to get the p values for the different tre and wa so that I can add significance values to a plot I created. I'm very new to statistical modelling in R so any suggestions to what I'm doing are welcome!

Comment: I think I've identified where this occurs. I wonder if you could try `emm <- emmeans(negbin, ~ tre | wa, data = test)` (i.e., add `data = test`) and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I did try that and it does help with one of the two errors, but I still see the following message:

Error in `[.data.frame`(tbl, , vars, drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected

I'm confused because "tre" and "wa" are my columns

Comment: Well, what that message says is it can't find one or both of those variables. I did a test with another NB model and it worked. Are things up-to-date? Do `packageVersion("emmeans")` and  `packageVersion("MASS")` ; you should have 1.8.4.1 and 7.3.58.1 respectively. If not, start over with a clean session and do `install.packages(c("emmeans", "MASS")` before loading either of those packages.

Comment: It looks like those are the same versions that I'm working with. Do you know of a way to specify the columns further? Earlier on I specified in my script that 
`tre = factor(test$treatment) 
wa=factor(test$warr) 
rep=factor(test$replic)`

However, my data set is of various length, i.e. for certain treatments, there are more or less replicates than others. Would this maybe have an effect on this response?

Comment: What's needed is for `tre` and `wa` to be variables that exist in your dataset. So did you you fit the model using the actual code `negbin <- glm.nb(flwrs ~ tre*wa + (1 | replic), data = test)`? The error message tells me those variables are not in the dataset, which makes me think the model was actually fitted using some other code, or that the dataset has changed.

Comment: Following up further, I think I'm seeing this: `tre = factor(test$treatment)` creates the variable `tre` in your *workspace*, not in `test`. I think you need to do `test$tre = factor(test$treatment)`, and similarly create variables `test$wa` and `test$rep`. Then re-fit the model and go from there (actually I think it may work without re-fitting).

Comment: I recently read this article [https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/FAQs.html] and tried out a suggestion they made in the "I wanted comparisons but all I get is nothing" section. I think you're right because I tried `negbin2 <- glm.nb(flwrs ~ factor(treatment) * factor(warr), data = test)`
`emm <- emmeans(negbin2, ~warr | treatment, data = test)`
`pairs(emm, adjust = "tukey")` and everything worked! Thanks for everything!!!

Comment: It's kind of a subtle situation because `glm.nb` and other model-fitting functions are happy to use variables in your global environment rather than in the dataset supplied. And once you start a new session, those global variables are likely no longer available.